# I want menu drops when I clicked, but it dont works (css)

Tags: html, css

I want menu drops when I click on it, but it opens and closes very fast.
I want to create my own web-site, but I'm still learning...
Html works, but css doesn't. I don't want to use `:hover`.
Hope you can help me
Thanks a lot,
Ivan

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow');

* {
    font-family : Tw Cen MT Condensed, PT Sans Narrow, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

#site_name {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30pt;
    color: #f71f1f;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

/* Primary menu */

#primary-menu {
    background: #b9b9b9;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

#primary-menu > div.container {
    float: right;
}

#primary-menu > div.container > ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#primary-menu > div.container > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 0 13px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#drop {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#primary-menu > div.container > ul > li:active > #drop {
    display: block;
    border-top: 5px solid white;
}

#drop > li {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    width: 120px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

#drop > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ed6161;
    font-size: 15pt;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

#primary-menu > div.container > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ed6161;
    height: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#primary-menu > div.container > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: #eb3434;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tw Cen MT Condensed... !-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IVANTEPLOV</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
 
    <!-- /header -->
    <header id="header">
        <div id="primary-menu">
            <div id="site_name">
            <a class="icon">IVANTEPLOV</a>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Программирование</a>
                        <ul id="drop">
                        <li><a href="#">WEB</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Java</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Техновости</a>
                    <ul id="drop">
                        <li><a href="#">Новейшее</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Гаджеты</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Защищенность</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know, this isn't language exchange, but regarding the title: "it *doesn't* work"

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach here is to employ some jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('li#drop').on('click', function () {
  $('ul').toggleClass('showing')
 });
});
```

...is not exact code, but I think you can figure it out from there?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **:hover** to display the next level menus. Only way to get the effect you want using CSS only. If you want some effect try to add "transition" parameter to the li/ul:

```
ul li{
    transition: all 0.75s;
}
ul li ul{ 
    display: none;
    opacity: 0; 
}
ul li:hover ul{ 
    display: block;
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

If don't have to use hover, you need to search for JS resolution, assign those categories into your question.

Comment: @mayersdesign lol, just saw the categories he assigned and ignored the "onclick" stuff. You're right. Let's wait for his feedback so.

Comment: OK no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This should effectively do what you are looking for. I believe there might be a more efficient way through some jQuery as suggested above so you don't have to have redundancies in the CSS.

Changed the href and id tags to distinguish the menus:

```
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#drop">Программирование</a>
          <ul id="drop">
            <li><a href="#">WEB</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Java</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#drop2">Техновости</a>
          <ul id="drop2">
            <li><a href="#">Новейшее</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Гаджеты</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Защищенность</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS using :target pseudo-selector instead of :active

```
#drop {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#drop:target {
    display: block;
}

#drop > li {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    width: 120px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

#drop > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ed6161;
    font-size: 15pt;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

#drop2 {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#drop2:target {
    display: block;
}

#drop2 > li {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    width: 120px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

#drop2 > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ed6161;
    font-size: 15pt;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9s070o3w/1/